# Contact form doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with a form, I can't send it. If I put wrong details (secure code, email, empty fields etc.), I get errors on screen, which is correct.

But when I enter all correct data, I can't send the form, I get this error:

> There was an error submitting your form. Please check the following:

But the list is empty.

```
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    try
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("noreply@domain.com", "string1");
        // decide who message goes to
        string emailGoesTo = "person1@domain.com";

        MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(emailGoesTo.ToString(), "string1");

        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.To.Add(toAddress);
        message.To.Add("person2@domain.com");
        message.Subject = "string2";
        message.Body = "New Website Contact Request";
        message.Body += "------------------------------------------\r\n";
        message.Body += "Name: " + your_name.Text + "\r\n";
        message.Body += "Email: " + your_email.Text + "\r\n";
        message.Body += "Telephone: " + your_telephone.Text + "\r\n";
        message.Body += "Company: " + your_company.Text + "\r\n";
        message.Body += "Address: " + your_address.Text + "\r\n";
        message.Body += "Postcode: " + your_zip.Text + "\r\n";
        message.Body += "Enquiry: " + your_enquiry.Text + "\r\n";

        // smtpClient.Host = "string3";
        smtpClient.Host = "string4";
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("string5", "string6");
        smtpClient.Send(message);
        Response.Redirect("thankyou.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "Coudn't send the message!";
    }
```

I'm noobie, so is there any1 `string5` & `string6` please?

Also what is wrong? How to make this form working?

Comment: have you walked through the code in debug to see where it fails?   My first guess is the format or the info for smtpclient.host is wrong.  If you are using exchange, your email server needs to allow relay from whatever machine is generating the email (your ip for testing) but that generally doesn't throw an error it just doesn't send the mail. I've added an example of a working mail send as an answer that you can start from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never tried to use smtpclient.host but the below works.  Just need to add in the ip/host name of the mail server and make sure it is set up to allow relay from the machine calling the code.  and replace the strings with the text you want.  I'd suggest starting with something simple rather than feeding from form fields to eliminate any outside issues.  Once the mail is sending then start adding additional pieces in.

```
    public static string mailServer = 'IP address or host name of mail server'
    public static void Send()
    {
        string subject = "test subject";
        string address =  "test@somedomain.com";
        string body = "some mail body";
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        mm.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@domain.net"); //on behalf of
        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));


        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Subject = subject;
        mm.Body = body;
        SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
        server.Send(mm);
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for reply, I'm afraid I can't debug this, because I have only Visual Studion demo. I code in php and dont know too much about asp, and dont have tools. I think all emails goes to exchange. I guess client change something and thats why I get this error. Is there a way to send contact form/email in a different way?

Comment: try just the code above and set the address to your email address and see if it works.  If it does then you can start replacing parts that you need from your code.  if it doesn't then the issue is going to be how the server is being called.  with this code you just need the ip address or url (i.e. mail.domainname.com) of the mail server.

Answer (score 2):

string5 and string6 is email credentials on mail server (username and password). You should know it better us ;-)

Comment: yes, I agree I should know that, it was in my mind but wasn't sure. This website was taken by client from his old supplier, and he give it to us. And I code in php, not asp :) thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your smtpClinet.Host with the name / domain information for your mail server.  The Credentials need to be updated with the username and password of a user that can access your mail server.  Sometimes this can be left out.